# MacBook Pro fan running with no CPU load and computer is COLD

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, temperature, cooling

Under normal circumstances (not installed new programs recently; had the usual programs running) I found my MacBook Pro 13" (Early 2015) with the fans running at average speed.

I always have the Activity Monitor CPU load indicator in Dock, to keep an eye at CPU usage, but this time it was not some program that got stuck using 100% CPU.

I downloaded iStat Menus to check temperatures, and I confirmed everything is **cold**:

```
Air Flow Proximity: 38°C
Battery TS1: 33°C
Battery TS2: 32°C
Battery TS_MAX: 33°C
CPU Core 1: 43°C
CPU Core 2: 42°C
CPU Gfx Core: 42°C
CPU Proximity: 41°C
CPU System Agent Core: 44°C
DDR3 Proximity: 39°C
PCH PECI Die: 45°C
Palm Rest: 32°C
Palm Rest 2: 31°C
Right Fin Stack: 36°C
SSD: 36°C
Hard Drive: 35°C

Fan: 6198rpm

CPU Vcore: 1.87V
DC In: 16.45V
PBus: 12.93V
```

These values are steady since half an hour, and the fan keeps running at this speed.

Do temperature values look normal?
The computer chassis is **cold**, and the air blowing from behind function keys also is cold.

What could be the cause and what can I do?

Comment: Have you tried performing an SMC reset?

Comment: Nope. I just found [this page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) and I'm going to try it right now.

Comment: @mescalinum Did the SMC-reset work?

Comment: @flindeberg nope. now I no longer own that macbook